# How a detached node could merge into a git branch?

Tags: git

I am using [GitKraken](http://www.gitkraken.com/) on Windows. While I was pulling remote branch into local, I saw this wired log graph, *circled in the image*. It looks like there's a detached node, a node without parent, but it is able to merge with another branch...not sure what does this means, any idea?

[image]

## Update after @VonC's comment

In this image, the commit with hash prefix **52a66d2** is the problematic one, and it looks like it had a parent in this view.

So maybe it is **GitKraken**'s fault?

[image]

Comment: What does a git status returns? Or a `git log --graph --pretty=format:'%Cred%h%Creset -%C(yellow)%d%Creset %s %Cgreen(%cr) %C(bold blue)<%an>%Creset' --abbrev-commit --date=relative --branches --all`? Do you see that commit there? (I am using gitkraken 0.2.11 myself)

Comment: ah~, the meta data in that commit actually says it has a parent. But that commit did not rendered in the client.

Comment: Sounds like a bug to report. Can you reproduce the issue on a new repo? or examine the logs starting from 52a66d2 to check its content?

Comment: Lol~I found out commit 52a66d2 is committed almost 3 hours earlier than its parent which commit 3058015...*the left one in the circle in the 1st image*. I guess it is still a bug, but a minor one. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I found out commit 52a66d2 is committed almost 3 hours earlier than its parent which commit 3058015

That means 52a66d2 has a parent (3058015), and its parent link is shown.

But the display order might *not* be topological (the parents are not always shown *before* the children) but using `--date=relative`.

(see also [`git show-branch`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-show-branch), which defines the two orders)